# Using R to process Mail Files

Tags: r

I've done a bit of searching and after not finding much I thought I would post this question.  Actually, because I've not found much, I think that may be an indicator of what the answer will be, but anyway...here it is:

Does anyone have any experience using R to process files for postal mailings...and if so...what packages do you use?

I realize R might not be the best tool for this task but sometimes you have to use the tools you have at hand and sometimes you have to do "extra" things at work to stay employed...so please don't flame me too hard for this question.

Basically I'm looking at merge purge, dup/elim sort of stuff.  I've played with the compare() and merge() commands a bit.  I'd like to incorporate some equivalencies in the compares such as

ST=St=St.=Street

BLVD=Blvd=Blvd.=Boulevard
etc...

I'm mostly wondering if packages have already been developed for this sort of data processing so I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: This question is a bit vague. What exactly are your inputs and intended output? The street thing sounds like a pretty simple regexp problem, but that depends on what your data look like.

Comment: Try tapping into the google map API which can often clean addresses for you.  Have a look at the `geoplot` package

Comment: Mostly it looks like basic addressing info: first name, last name 2 or 3 address lines, city, state, zip. I'll have 4 or 5 lists from different sources.  I want to combine the lists and remove duplicate records but I'm wanting to include some logic when comparing.  Wondering if this was a wheel already invented.

Comment: I didnt downvote this question, but I can see why it is being downvoted.  Perhaps you can re-phrase the question into something more concrete

Comment: I think between the post title and the brief description I gave, it is pretty clear what I'm trying to accomplish.  This is a very general question.  Where I say,"Does anyone have any experience using R to process files for postal mailings...and if so...what packages do you use?"  I was only expecting people who fit into the category to respond.

Comment: @WillPhillips StackOverflow is meant for to-the-point programming questions, not for broad `I'd like to do something like this` questions. So in a general sense it is clear what you want, but that is not how SO works. If you have concrete questions like `I tried using gsub to try and homogenize how 'street' is used, I have done this and this (including example data and concrete code) but I have a hard time getting it to work`, you are welcome to post them here.

Comment: OK thank you for that input.  I'm not on SO often and have only posted here a few times.  My apologies. I was unaware SO had that standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest the following basic workflow:

(1) Read in your data. I don't know what it looks like based on your question, so I'll assume that's easy for you.

(2) Use a mix of `gsub`, `toupper`, and other string manipulation tools to convert all the data to the same formats. I.e., get all addresses to use ST instead of St or street, etc.

(3) `merge` everything into a single dataframe.

(4) Use `unique` and/or `sort`/`order` to clean up the list and remove duplicates.

(5) Output to whatever format you're going for. Again, not clear from the question, so I can't offer specific advice here.

Comment: This is great.  I'm not familiar with gsub or toupper so this gives me a few more areas to research, which is what I was looking for. At this point I'm just trying to compile a list of tools in R for this sort of data manipulation. I appreciate the input.  Sorry for not posting a specific problem.